# What would be the result of the given cartesian product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What if a null set is an element of a set out of the two between which cartesian product is to be performed?

I mean {1,2, phi } x { 2, 3, 4}

Also , discuss about questions like

{1,2,{1,2}} x { {3,4} , 3 ,4}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also note that given two sets $A$ and $B$, we have that $A \times B := \{ (a,b) \ | \ a \in A, \ b \in B \}$

Comment: "discuss about questions like" is unclear

Answer (score 3):

You can just treat it as another element of the set. For instance,

$$\{1, 2, \phi \} \times \{2, 3, 4\} = \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (\phi, 2), (\phi, 3), (\phi, 4) \}$$

For your second question, you can also view it as $X = \{1, 2\}, Y = \{3, 4\}$ and do $\{1, 2, X\} \times \{Y, 3, 4\}$ and substitute as needed.

Comment: Yep, the sets are just elements of the set that contains them.

Comment: Yep, just apply the definition. It does not matter whether the element is another set, the empty set, a real number or an object in real life. Also some axiomatic construction of natural numbers actually define 0 as the empty set so it is pretty common that sets in general and the empty set can be elements of other sets.